# How to deal with "for loop elements" with calculation in shell scripts using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am doing a loop operation with shell scripts under Windows Powershell. The simple float calculation with loop elements shows as following:

```
for L2 in 0.95 0.5 0.05
  do
    L1=$((1.0-$L2))
    echo $L1
done
```

I Expect:

L1 should be 0.05,0.5,0.95

However following error message comes:

```
1.0-0.95: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0-0.95")
```

and I notice someone suggested adding a "| bc" to do float calculation such as following:

```
L1=$((1.0-$L2) | bc)
```

however seems powershell don't have bc option and returns:

```
 1.0-0.05: command not found
 bc: command not found
 L1 Value:
```

Comment: Do you perhaps need to put a space before the 1.0 and after $L2?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tried, the error message of < 1.0-0.95 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0-0.95 ") > still comes out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to use a Unix construct (`$((...))`) in a Windows shell. PowerShell understands [arithmetic operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6) without it:

```
 $L1 = 1.0 - $L2
```

Notice that the target variable is prefixed with `$`, which differs from bash as well.

Your loop syntax is bash-specific as well. You will have to use a proper [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-6) or [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6) loop instead of what you have.

All in all, you have to take into account that Windows PowerShell is not a Unix shell, specifically not bash, and write your code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I tried your script and it shows <=: command not found>

Comment: I've added links to some additional documentation. The fundamental problem is that PowerShell is not bash.

Comment: So.... if I want to do this kind of calculation, any suggestion that made me can run this code in Windows environment?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you will have to look through the linked docs or find a different tutorial. I'm not qualified to do that, and Stack Overflow is not the right forum for it.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I think I will try to do with the simple way this time